# How to logout using openid4java API?

Tags: session, openid, logout, invalidation, openid4java

After verifying/validating with provider, I want to logout from provider application (or invalidate provider application session). Please let me know which openid4java API to use.

Note: InMemoryConsumerAssociationStore.remove( opURL, handle) is not working.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add logout feature to an OpenID enabled site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968814/how-to-add-logout-feature-to-an-openid-enabled-site)

Comment: Steve: Thanks much for the pointer. I agree with your comment. I did search before posting but with "openid4java" and that's the reason, I guess, I missed out.

Comment: All: Any idea what does calling "InMemoryConsumerAssociationStore.remove( opURL, handle)" do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no logout in OpenID, the logout process is for your local session management.